# Confusion on Nesting if statements with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So this program im basically missing a couple things:

- Make sure wage is not less than 0
- Make sure hours is not less than 40 and also greater than 0.

My issue is that I do not know how to approach this. Initially I thought I could add an If statement into the first If statement of each, but the value being stored in scan is not available until it is scanned, which is after the first If statement. How would I make such a statement to check such?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayrollCC{
public static void main (String [] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


double wage=0;
int hours=0;
boolean bool = false;
final int MAXHOURS = 40;

do{
    System.out.println("Please enter your hourly wage: ");
    
    if(scan.hasNextDouble() && !scan.hasNextInt()){
        wage = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        bool = true;
    }
    else{
        bool = false;
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    
    
} while(!bool);



    do{
    System.out.println("Please enter how many hours you have worked this week: ");
    
    if(scan.hasNextInt()){
        hours = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        if(hours > MAXHOURS && hours < 0){
            bool = false;
        }
        
        bool = true;
    }
    else{
        bool = false;
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    
    
} while(!bool);

double week = (hours*wage);
double total = (week);
double avg = (week);


System.out.println("Week's pay: $"+(week)+"   Total pay: $"+(total)+"   Average pay per week: $"+(avg));



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would have implemented it. I don't know if this is entirely helpful to you, but if not I am happy to answer any questions about it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayrollCC{
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double wage = 0;
        int hours = 0;
        final int MAX_HOURS = 40;

        //Get user's wage
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter your wage: ");
            wage = scan.nextDouble();
        } while (wage < 0);

        //Get user's hours worked
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter how many hours you have worked this week: ");
            hours = scan.nextInt();
        } while ((hours > 40) || (hours < 0));


        double week = (hours*wage);
        double total = (week);
        double avg = (week);


        System.out.println("Week's pay: $"+(week)+"   Total pay: $"+(total)+"   Average pay per week: $"+(avg));

    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you could select this thread as solved, or if not I would be happy to answer any new questions